# Pycharm does not support Blenders Bpy package

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to use Blenders bpy package in Pycharm.

I'm using the correct version of Python (3.10)

And have used pip to install the bpy package

[image]

But Pycharm does not seem recognise to have any sub packages of bpy

[image]

[image]

As far as I can tell the paths virtual machine have the correct paths setup

[image]

But Pycharm does not does not reconise the bpy folder under site-packages as a python module

[image]

Is there any way to fix this

Comment: Did you follow official instructions (https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule) or just used `pip install bpy`?

Comment: @FN_ I have just used pip install

Comment: @FN_ I have built bpy, using official instructions and I seem to get the same result as just downloading from pip